# Is it possible to make PHP errors look nicer? Can Stack trace output on separate lines?

Tags: formatting, php

Right now PHP simply dumps something like this on the page:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare Cms\getItemHierarchy() (previously
>   declared in
>   /home/cartman/Development/cmsdev/engine_1.0/Cms/Menu.php:62) in
>   /home/cartman/Development/cmsdev/engine_1.0/Cms/Menu.php on line 62
>   Call Stack: 0,0001 634424 1. {main}()
>   /home/cartman/Development/cmsdev/public_normal/index.php:0 0,0037
>   757768 2. Bootstrap::run()
>   /home/cartman/Development/cmsdev/public_normal/index.php:7 0,0037
>   757768 3. Cms\Front->dispatch()
>   /home/cartman/Development/cmsdev/data_production/bootstrap.php:94
>   0,0043 781512 4. frontendController->contactusAction()
>   /home/cartman/Development/cmsdev/engine_1.0/Cms/Front.php:367 0,0051
>   817152 5. plugins\m3nu\api->renderMenu($configName = 'bottom',
>   $activeItem = 'contactme')
>   /home/cartman/Development/cmsdev/data_production/controllers/frontendController.php:43
>   0,0052 825392 6. Cms\Menu->generateMenu()
>   /home/cartman/Development/cmsdev/public_normal/plugins/m3nu/api.php:29
>   0,0052 825392 7. Cms\Menu->preParseConfig()
>   /home/cartman/Development/cmsdev/engine_1.0/Cms/Menu.php:121

Is there a way to make the output look more organized, at least print stack trace on separate lines?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be an XDebug stack trace. Try setting [trace_format](http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#trace_format) in `php.ini`:

```
xdebug.trace_format = 2 # HTML formatting
```

Comment: Yep. I've set it to 2 that but output is still on one line.

Comment: Oh - I had to also set html_errors=On in php.ini for xdebug to use nice orange formatting. Works for me.

Answer (score 12):

You can also update the **php.ini** to include some formatting HTML.

```
html_errors = On
error_prepend_string = "<pre style='color: #333; font-face:monospace; font-size:8pt;'>"
error_append_string = "</pre>"
```

Or if you'd prefer to set them at runtime include the following at the top of your script(s)

```
ini_set("html_errors", "1"); 
ini_set("error_prepend_string", "<pre style='color: #333; font-face:monospace; font-size:8pt;'>"); 
ini_set("error_append_string ", "</pre>");
```

Comment: I would do this instead: ini_set("error_prepend_string", "<pre style='color: #333; font-family: source-code-pro, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, 'Courier New', monospace; font-size:14px;'>");

Answer (score 4):

If you are viewing them from a browser, you can wrap it in

`<pre></pre>`

tags which will essentially present your newline characters as line breaks.

Otherwise, if you are viewing outside of DOM, i.e., in console or source viewer, you will find they are already formatted "nicely"

Comment: Is ther some php.ini directive that allows me to wrap erorr output?

Comment: You can just warp <?php ?> tags with <pre></pre> tags